# Java - Android: Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: java, android

I want to open the detail of a cardview selected and Im trying to take the onlcick and open a new intent but Android Studio throw the next exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo, PID: 5200
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo/es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Fragments.DetalleFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
at es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Models.NewsViewHolder$1.onClick(NewsViewHolder.java:32)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is the code of my ViewHolder:

```
public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    Context context;

    public NewsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetalleFragment.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        TextView post_titular = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        post_titular.setText(titular);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
}
```

And this is my **DetalleFragment.java**

```
public class DetalleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detalle, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this my **fragment_detalle.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Fragments.DetalleFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello from detail"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `DetalleFragment` is a *fragment*. It is not an *activity*. You do not use `startActivity()` to show a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

DetalleFragment is a fragment. You need activity class to inflate fragment. 
You cannot directly call startActivity() for DetalleFragment.

Create an activity class and inflate DetalleFragment and then call startActivity() for that activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity to inflate the fragment.